# SQL Server BCP of Unicode XML and Powershell conversion to UTF-8 producing weirdness with return characters

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell, character-encoding, bcp

Background: I'm writing a stored procedure in SQL Server to produce an export of some of our data. The files need to be in XML format, so I'm BCPing them out with `for xml` in the query.

String data is `varchar` (not `nvarchar`), but some characters weren't converting correctly, so we changed the BCP statement to use `-w` instead of `-CACP`. Our end user balked at the filesize, requesting UTF-8 instead, and we wanted to put in an XML directive statement so the files are more "correct" XML; a little Powershell seemed to take care of both.

Generally speaking, the process is doing what we want, but there is some weirdness with data that contains CR/LFs inside -- namely, it appears that the BCP converts the CRs to the string "$#x0D;", but leaves the LFs as 0x0A (well, the Unicode equivalent, with a 0x00 byte too).  Then, the Powershell statement appears to treat the "$#x0D;" as just more text data, and it turns the (Unicode) 0x0A into a (UTF-8) space.  This is not what we want!  What's interesting is that if I leave the XML directive part out, the (Unicode) 0x0A gets converted back to a (UTF-8) CR/LF, but it leaves the "$#x0D;" in the data too.

I've provided a streamlined example of what we're doing below; change `MyDatabase` to a working DB, and change the `C:\` path to whatever works, and you can see the resulting files -- I'm using TextPad to see them visually, and HexEdit to inspect the actual byte by byte output -- that result.  Does anyone see anything obvious that might help?  I've been Googling a bit but can't seem to find anything relevant to our particular situation...

```
create table MyDatabase.dbo.TestTable (
  StringData varchar (1000)
)

insert into MyDatabase.dbo.TestTable (StringData)
    select 
        'I have return characters in me.' + char (13) + char (10) + 'Will the file I''m output to be okay?'

declare @Query varchar (2000)
declare @Command varchar (2000)

set @Query = 'select * '
            + 'from MyDatabase.dbo.TestTable with (nolock) '
            + 'for xml path (''StringData''), root (''TableData''), elements, type'

set @Command = 'bcp "' + @Query + '" queryout C:\TestXMLUnicodeData_1.xml -w -T -S' + cast( @@ServerName as varchar )

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command

set @Command = 'powershell "Get-Content  C:\TestXMLUnicodeData_1.xml | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 C:\TestXMLUTF8Data_1.xml'

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command

set @Query = 'select * '
            + 'from MyDatabase.dbo.TestTable with (nolock) '
            + 'for xml path (''StringData''), root (''TableData''), elements, type'

set @Command = 'bcp "' + @Query + '" queryout C:\TestXMLUnicodeData_2.xml -w -T -S' + cast( @@ServerName as varchar )

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command

set @Command = 'powershell "''<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'' + (Get-Content  C:\TestXMLUnicodeData_2.xml)'
              + ' | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 C:\TestXMLUTF8Data_2.xml'

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the FOR XML/ BCP doesn't encode the LF as well as the CR.

However, the reason you are getting the space inserted in your second file is because of how Get-Content and powershell's automatic string array enumeration behave.

Get-Content defaults to reading one line at a time and actually returns an array of strings that contain lines from your data file.   In your example Get-Content is using the LF character as it's EOL terminator ( the EOL terminator is then discarded from your data ).

See this blog post for a good write up of how Get-Content works.
http://powershell.org/wp/2013/10/21/why-get-content-aint-yer-friend/

The space is then getting inserted because of how powershell automatically enumerates string arrays.

```
$a = "One", "Two", "Three" 
$a 
Write-Output ( "The string concatentation causes an automatic enumeration of the string array.  Notice the automatic spaces inserted after data at index zero" + $a )
```

Using the -RAW option on the Get-Content command as that blog recommends seems to get the output you're looking for because Get-Content will return an array with one item so there's no automatic spaces appended.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  Unfortunately, I think it's the first thing that's causing the most trouble.  I ended up going more work to explicitly encode both CR and LF in the beginning of the process, and using Powershell to replace the encoded strings back out to CR/LF in the ending.  What are a few more CPU cycles, after all?  :-/